# How to update registrationid by registrationname in to first table by finding registrationid by registrationname from second table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012

I have two table name as **Table1** and **Table2** in which all the columns are same.

```
Table1:RegistrationId,Registration,Amount
Table2:RegistrationId,Registration,Amount.
```

Now in Table2 i have all the records and RegistrationId too but in Table1 i dont have RegistrationId so i just want to insert appropriate registrationId in to Table1 by Appropriate registration name.

I want to fetch one by one registrationname from table2 and find RegistrationId and insert that 
RegistrationId in to Table1 in to appropriate registration name.

**Table2**:

```
RegistrationId    Registration  Amount
 1                 Abc           100
 2                 pqr           200
 3                 xyz           300
 4                 yyy           300
```

**Table1**:

```
RegistrationId    Registration  Amount
                  Abc           100
                  pqr           200
                  xyz           300
                  lmn           400
                  uuu           800
```

Expected Output:
Table1:

```
RegistrationId    Registration  Amount
      1            Abc           100
      2            pqr           200
      3            xyz           300
                   lmn           400
                   uuu           800
```

So how to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MERGE INTO Table1
   USING Table2
      ON Table1.Registration  = Table2.Registration 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET Table.RegistrationId = Table2.RegistrationId;
```

or

```
UPDATE
    Table1
SET
    Table1.RegistrationId = Table2.RegistrationId
FROM
    Table1
INNER JOIN
    Table2
ON Table1.Registration  = Table2.Registration
```